# Check for amount of line breaks — winapi c++

Tags: c++, winapi, text, static

I have a static text control that should resize along with the window, its text width is smaller than the whole line of text at first, so it clips like I need by default.

I would like to center the text vertically. When it is clipped the whole height is occupied, but when static's width is large enough and the whole text fits into one line it is up high. How can I center it wherever it is?

[image]

Comment: I thought there was a style you could set in the static control to do vertical alignment, but I can't find it.  You can do horizontal alignment with styles like [`SS_CENTER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-control-styles).

Comment: @MarkRansom I do already have `SS_CENTER`. If you meant `SS_CENTERIMAGE` it doesn't work for me, because with it the text doesn't clip.

Comment: A `STATIC` control does not support vertical alignment.  You will have to use the `SS_OWNERDRAW` style and draw the text manually using `DrawText/Ex()`, which has `DT_CENTER` and `DT_VCENTER` flags. `DT_VCENTER` only works when the `DT_SINGLELINE` flag is also used, though.

Comment: Since you didn't include any code in your question it's impossible to see which styles you included or didn't.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think it's a coincidence that the static control doesn't support vertical alignment when the text API doesn't either.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `DT_SINGLELINE`: Displays text on a single line only. **Carriage returns and line feeds do not break the line**.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT yes, I'm aware of that, as well as "*`DT_VCENTER`: Centers text vertically. **This value is used only with the DT_SINGLELINE value**.*"  It is not that hard to figure out if text has any line breaks in it, or if the text would be word-wrapped (`DT_CALCRECT` can be used to determine that)

Comment: @RemyLebeau You may misunderstand what I mean. When you add  `DT_VCENTER` and `DT_SINGLELINE` styles, you will find that single-line text will not be clipped. This is different from what OP expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found that you can customize the height of the upper left corner of the text to achieve vertical centering. Of course, the text can be truncated.

When the length of the static control is less than the length of the text, the text will be truncated. So we need to calculate the height and length of the text, with the help of [GetTextExtentPoint32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextextentpoint32a). Then [DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) does the rest, `DT_WORDBREAK` and `DT_CENTER` should be added.

See my code for specific details:

```
// Parent Hwnd
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0, 0, 800, 600, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

// Window Process
float nScale_x = 1.0, nScale_y = 1.0;
HWND static_hwnd;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    RECT rc;   // the size of text
    RECT rect; // the size of Rectangle       
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        static_hwnd = CreateWindow(L"STATIC",
            L"Some clipping text example",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | SS_OWNERDRAW,
            100, 100, 200, 50, 
            hWnd,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);
 
        return 1;
    }
    case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
        if (pDIS->hwndItem == static_hwnd)
        {          
            const wchar_t* text = L"Some clipping text example";
            HDC hDC = pDIS->hDC;
            RECT rect = pDIS->rcItem;
            RECT rc;

            int w = rect.right - rect.left;
            int h;
            if (w >= 180) // the length of "Some clipping text example"
            {
                h = 16;
            }
            else if (w < 92) //the length of "Some clipping"
            {
                h = 16 * 3;
            }
            else if (w < 180) 
            {
                h = 16 * 2;
            }
            rc.left = rect.left;
            rc.right = rect.right;
            rc.top = ((rect.bottom - rect.top) - h) / 2;
            rc.bottom = rect.bottom;

            HBRUSH bg = (HBRUSH)(::GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH));
            HPEN pn = (HPEN)(::GetStockObject(BLACK_PEN));
            ::SelectObject(hDC, bg);

            //SIZE sz;
            //GetTextExtentPoint32(hDC, text, 13, &sz); 
            ::SelectObject(hDC, pn);
            ::SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(0, 0, 0));           
            ::Rectangle(hDC, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
            ::DrawText(hDC, text, wcslen(text), &rc, DT_WORDBREAK | DT_CENTER); 
        }
        return TRUE;
    }        
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);
        nScale_x = (rc.right - rc.left) / 800.0;
        nScale_y = (rc.bottom - rc.top) / 600.0;
        SetWindowPos(static_hwnd, NULL, 100, 100, 200 * nScale_x, 50 * nScale_y, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }        
    ...
```

Debug:

[image]